# stenciljs removes theme param

Tags: ionic-framework, stenciljs

Stencil.js automaticaly remove `theme` param.

This code

```
<div>
  <vaadin-button theme="primary">Login</vaadin-button>
</div>
```

converts to

```
<div>
  <vaadin-button tabindex="0" role="button">Login</vaadin-button>
</div>
```

example
https://webcomponents.dev/edit/aJViPAjm35yATrrylWk1

Comment: I can confirm this behavior in our own app. I suggest opening an issue.

Comment: I just looked into this again, trying to better understand the Stencil internals. I believe the problem is in [`isMemberInElement()`](https://github.com/ionic-team/stencil/blob/65006a1c0484c7048b30e26814cddc73cfc8afba/src/client/client-host-ref.ts#L33) because `('theme' in document.querySelector('vaadin-button')) === true` in which case Stencil sets a property, not an attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Here is test code to find out which one changes your DOM attribute.

```
import { h, Component, Prop } from "@stencil/core";
//commented deliberately
//import "@vaadin/vaadin-button/vaadin-button";

<!-- OUTPUT -->
<custom-element name="you">
    <vaadin-button part="vaadin-login-submit" theme="primary contained">
      Submit
    </vaadin-button>
</custom-element>
```

As we can see from the above, Stencil JS itself does not manipulate your vaadin-button DOM attribute.

I assume that @vaadin/vaadin-button library has conflicts with Stencil JS.

**Update**

It seems Stencil JS has some issues with work with web component library.

https://github.com/ionic-team/stencil/issues/529

https://github.com/ionic-team/stencil/issues/1095

**By-pass way** 
It does not looks good, but it works.

```
import { Component, h, Element} from '@stencil/core';
import "@vaadin/vaadin-button/vaadin-button";

@Component({
  tag: 'app-root',
  shadow: false
})

export class AppRoot {

  @Element() private element: HTMLElement;

  componentDidLoad(){
    [].forEach.call(this.element.querySelectorAll('vaadin-button'), (dom) => {
      dom.setAttribute('theme','primary contained')
    }); 
  }

  render() {
    return (
          <vaadin-button theme="primary contained">FROM ROOT</vaadin-button>
    );
  }
}
```